# Number 9 is being replaced by dash "—" in the system

Tags: gnome, 20.04, fonts

My Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS. The problem is, everywhere in the system UI the number 9 is being rendered as long dash "—". This only happens in UI fonts and sometimes in Browser too. It works fine in the text editors. This problem was there since first install of Ubuntu 20.04.

This is how calender looks in my system:

[image: Screenshot of calendar]

Comment: That sounds as an issue with the font. Do you know which font is used in those UIs where the issue is present?

Comment: Try refreshing the font cache: `fc-cache -r -v`

Comment: Changing the interface font worked. Thank You

Comment: same problem here and `fc-cache -r -v` dindt work